# Не удаляется запиь из БД PHP

Tags: php

прошу помощи есть страница с записями из БД, пытаюсь сделать удаление при нажатии на кнопку по id, код написал, но при нажатии запись не удаляется в чем дело понять не могу

`````
require_once "../lib/orders_class.php";

//Заявки
$class=new Orders;
$filtermasterr=$class->database->select("users", "id>0");
for ($i=0; $i<count($filtermasterr); $i++){
    $filtermaster.="<li><a href='?master=".$filtermasterr[$i][id]."'>".$filtermasterr[$i][username]."</a></li>";
    if ($filtermasterr[$i][id]==$_GET[master])$filteruser=$filtermasterr[$i][username];
    }

//Удалить
if ($_GET[deleteorders]){
    $error=$class->delete("order", "id='".$_GET[deleteorders]."'");
    if ($error=="1") echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=/order/'>";
    }   ````

Вот код самой функции 


    public function deleteorders($id){
        $error=$this->database->delete("orders", "id='".$id."'");   
        return $result;
    }
`````

Comment: обратите внимание, что `$_GET[deleteorders]` у вас имя ключа указано без кавычек, так что в логе пхп у вас куча ошибок по этому поводу. Также изучите что такое sql инъекции и как их избегать, в частности прочитай про подготовленные запросы и передачу параметров в них. По существу ошибки, у вас дважды прописано `id=` так что условие выходит вроде `id = ' id = 123'`. ну и какая-то непотная штука с refresh там есть.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял код стоит переписать так if ($_GET[delete]){
 $error=$class->delete("orders", "id='".$_GET['id']."'");
 if ($error=="1") echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=/orders/'>";
 }

Comment: После изменения получил 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Orders::delete() in

Comment: Переделал код if ($_GET[delete]){
 $error=$class->database->delete("orders", "id='".$_GET[$id]."'");
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=/orders/'>";
 } Но код все равно не работает

Comment: вы читайте мой коммент по одному предложению и исправляйте ровно то, что там написано.